# Limiting results of raw SQL Queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying limit the result returned by a raw SQL query using Entity Framework.
The problem is that the software does that at software level not at database level.

```
ctx.Database.SqlQuery<ViewModelQuery>(sql)
            .Skip(totalPage * (page - 1))
            .Take(totalPage)
            .ToList();
```

How can I solve this in a way that the command sent to database includes offset and fetch?

Comment: You should do it at entity level. For now your code sends pure SQL query.

Comment: you will want to add an orderby

Comment: What datatype returned from `Take`? An `IQueryable<>` or `IEnumerable<>`?

Comment: You need to include your SQL.  The [SqlQuery<T>()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbrawsqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) method returns a query ready to run.  You can't use Skip() or Take() and assume that .net can magically figure out how to modify your SQL to run it server side.  If you need your skip() and take() to run server side, then you need to modify your `sql` value.

Comment: Lastly the result of SqlQuery<T>() is of type IEnumerable<T> so the results are pulled to the client before Take() and Skip().  If it was IQueryable, you might have a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the only way to solve it, changing the `sql` query or provide Linq to Entities query. Because `Database.SqlQuery` already start to return records as `IEnumerable`. (It fetched by SQL Server already) It's form is not `IQueryable`. So, you have two options to perform it;

1. Changing the Sql query by taking and skipping form like this;

```sql
SELECT c1,c2 from where table
OFFSET     10 ROWS       -- skip 10 rows
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY; -- take 10 rows
```

2. Or you should provide the query as `Linq to Entities` to keep `IQueryable` form and perform `Skip` - `Take` .

Answer (score 1):

I assume ctx is an object of a class derived from DbContext.

Apparently you chose not to use LINQ to write your query, but you chose to use your own SQL command. Your variable sql is a string which contains the commands in your sql.

Then why not add the offset and fetch in this string:

```
 Select ....
 From ...
 ...
 OFFSET @Skip ROWS FETCH NEXT @Take ROWS ONLY;
```

It would work, but I think you should reconsider you decision to use sql statements once you decided to use entity framework. Your DbSet classes represent your tables, and your DbContext class knows the relations between your table. It is meant to hide that internally SQL is used to communicate with your database.

Users of your DbContext shouldn't have to know what methods are used to save the data. It could by a Database using SQl, or MySql, it could be Mongo, or even a spreadsheet file. This is hidden for users of your DbContext, thus allowing you to change database without having to change the users.

By using SQL in your interface you are violating this information hiding. Why don't you use Linq to query your page of ViewModelQuery items?